# Python in Task Manager or Background Services in Windows?

Tags: windows, python, services, task-manager

I just installed [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) on Windows system. Just like any software, curious if Python has a background service or program running in Task Manager or Services, when I'm not actually using the program.  I like to free up computing resources, and don't want unnecessary programs in the background.

I know SQL Server and Visual Studio can have that issue. Just want to verify. Checking down, I didn't see any.

[image: Windows Services image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python does not have any background services running. You will only see a Python executable in Task Manager or by using `tasklist` in a console when a Python script is actually being run or you are in the Python console environment.

```
C:\Users\Mike>where python
C:\python27\python.exe

C:\Users\Mike>where python3
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe

C:\Users\Mike>tasklist | find /i "python"

C:\Users\Mike>
```